# How to calculate packet loss in android?

Tags: android, api, network-programming, packet

How can we calculate all network or calculate specific Network packet loss in android?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Robert's answer, UDP is a datagram best-effort delivery protocol without any notion of sessions, in-order delivery, or error detection. If you want error detection, you'd probably end up implementing much of TCP (well, at least sequence numbers, checksums, and acknowledgements).

Luckily, for TCP, the kernel keeps track of detailed statistics. The standard `ip` utility should be of help here. On my SGS2, the utility is complete and not cut down like `ifconfig`.

Example usage:

```
root@android:/etc # ip -s -s link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    23692      410      0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    23692      410      0       0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
2: gannet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:e0:e5:0a:dc:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
3: sit0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        59      0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
4: ip6tnl0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1452 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        62      62      0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
5: rmnet0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ppp 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    1410177    2037     0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    199870     1831     0       0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
6: rmnet1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ppp 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0      
7: rmnet2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ppp 
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    RX errors: length  crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    0          0        0       0       0       0      
    TX errors: aborted fifo    window  heartbeat
               0        0       0       0
```

My phone's rooted but that's definitely not a requirement.

Comment: what If I want this information inside my android application ? Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can run the `ip` utility, capture the output and parse what you need from it. It'd be a pain to do across devices (link names change, the `ip` utility is not part of Android per se) but it looks possible.

Answer (score 0):

For TCP there may be a possibility to get the values on the Linux level, but not on Java/Android level.

For UDP it is impossible as there is no data included which could be used for detecting packet loss. If you want to calculate data loss on UDP level you have to implement your own UDP based protocol and include for example a packet counter. But that would allow you only to calculate packet loss for your own protocol, not on a general level.